# React Socket NodeJs SocketManager not pulling through

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Stuck in a problem, unable to understand why it is not working.
Everything seems okay.
Please advice.

This is Server.js

```
var app = module.exports.ie=require('http').createServer()
var io =  require('socket.io')(app)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3231
const socketManager = require('./socketManager')

io.on('connection', socketManager) 

app.listen(PORT, () =>
console.log(`Connected to Port ${PORT}`)

)
```

Below is the my Layout file which holds the main render.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { USER_CONNECTED, LOGOUT } from './ConstEvents';
import ChatNameForm  from './ChatNameForm';

const socketUrl = "http://localhost:3231"

export default class chatPane extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state ={
            socket:null,
            user: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.initSocket()
    }
    /*
    *
    *  Connect to 'socketUrl' and initialise the socket.
    * 
    */   
    initSocket =() =>{
        const socket = io(socketUrl)
        socket.on('connect', () =>{
            console.log("Connected");
        })
        this.setState({socket})
    }

    /*
    *   Sets the user property in state
    *   @Param user {id:number, name:string}
    */
    setUser = (user) =>{
        const { socket } = this.state
        socket.emit(USER_CONNECTED, user);
        this.setState({user})

    }

    /**
     * Sets the user property in state to Null.
     * 
     */
    logout = () => {
        const { socket } =  this.state
        socket.emit(LOGOUT);
        this.setState({user:null})
    }

    render(){
        const { socket } = this.state

        return(
            <div>
                <ChatNameForm socket={socket} setUser={this.setUser} />  

            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Below is the UserName form. No Passwords only setting up the user name here.

> import React, {Component} from 'react';
>       import VERIFY_USER from './ConstEvents';
>
> ```
> export default class ChatNameForm extends Component {
>     constructor(props){
>         super(props);
>         this.state = {
>             userChatName:"",
>             error:""
>         };
>     }
>
>     setUser = ({user, isUser}) => {
>         console.log(user, isUser);
>         if(isUser){
>             this.setError("User name Taken")
>         }
>         else {
>             this.props.setUser(user)
>             this.setError("")
>         }
>     }
>
>     handleSubmit = (e) => {
>         e.preventDefault()
>         const { socket } = this.props
>         const {userChatName} = this.state
>         socket.emit (VERIFY_USER, userChatName, this.setUser)
>
>     }
>
>     handleChange = (e) => {
>         this.setState({userChatName:e.target.value})
>
>     }
>
>     setError = (error) => {
>         this.setState({error})
>     }
>
>     render() {
>         const {userChatName, error} = this.state
>         return (
>             <div className='login'>
>                  <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} > 
>                  <label htmlFor= "userChatName">
>                     <h2>Enter User Chat Name</h2>
>                  </label>
>                  <input 
>                          ref = {(input) => { this.textinput = input}}
>                          type = "text"
>                          id ="userChatName"
>                          value = {userChatName}
>                          onChange={this.handleChange}
>                          placeholder={'userChatName'}
>                          />
>                 <input type="submit" value= "ok" />  
>                          <div className= "error">
>                              {error ? error:null}
>                          </div>
>
>                  </form>
>              </div>
>         )
>     }
> }
> ```

And lastly My SocketManager..

```
const io =  require('./Server.js').io

const { VERIFY_USER, USER_CONNECTED, LOGOUT } = require('../ConstEvents');
const { createUser, createMessage, createChat} = require('../ChatFunctions');

let connectedUsers = { }

module.exports = function(socket){
    console.log(`Socket Id = ${socket.id}`)

    // verify chatName  

    socket.on(VERIFY_USER, (userChatName, callback) => {

        if (isUser (connectedUsers, userChatName)) {
            callback ({ isUser:true, user:null })
        } else{
             callback ({ isUser:false, user:createUser({name:userChatName})})
            }
    })
    //User connects with userName
    socket.on(USER_CONNECTED, (user) => {
        connectedUsers= addUser(connectedUsers, user)
        socket.user = user
        io.emit(USER_CONNECTED, connectedUsers)  
    })
}
function addUser (userList, user){
    let newList = Object.assign({}, userList) 
    newList[user.name] = user
    return newList
}

function removeUser(userList, username){
    let newList = Object.assign({}, userList)
    delete newList[username]
    return newList
}

function isUser(userList, userChatName){

    return userChatName in userList
}
```

Issue; I can get the socket working fine. Value from Form fine however I this values are not being pushed over to socketManager. I have done some tests in Form Js to see if the handleSubmit is working or not.. I can see socket, userChatName and socket.emit is working fine. however when I go to socket manager and look into the triggered Event in this case VERIFY_USER... I don't see any results after that. tried testing it but not sure how too get its value out on console to test. If you can help me out plz. Thank you.

Comment: change your const socket = io(socketUrl) in initSocket function to const socket = io.connect(socketUrl); and try again.

Comment: Tnx Babar; plz see the layout file it is initiated as you suggested; as I mentioned above socket is being connecting fine. I m getting socket id however I cant get it over in Socket manager socket.io function to perform logic

Comment: I find whats your problem, notice to this your project have a two section: server side( server.js and SocketManager) and client side(ChatNameForm component), now you can't sent callback functions from your client to server ! you have to separate this two section and manage with socket.on both server and client by send command by emit, strongly recommend to review your project